# Unable to load database driver via Spring, but can manually find it on the classpath

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException on a database driver class when attempting to create a data source using Spring running under Tomcat. I am, however, able to load the driver class directly from the same data access component (both via `Class.forName` and `getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass()`). The driver jar is only installed in one place (`$CATALINA_HOME/lib`).

The data source definition in the Spring config file:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

The DAO definition in the Spring config file:

```
<bean id="countryDao" class="com.mycompany.pmo.dao.CountryDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

The DAO itself:

```
public class CountryDao {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public CountryDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        //I can manually load the driver class here
        String sql = "select * from ref.country";

        Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //next line is line 34, where the stack trace starts
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters,new CountryMapper());
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
Feb 20, 2013 2:18:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/PMO] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"'] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:702)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:172)
    at com.mycompany.pmo.dao.CountryDao.getCountries(CountryDao.java:34)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `jar` should not be in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. It should be in `WEB-INF/lib` of your web app. I believe `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` will be used to load and run `Tomcat`, but your app classpath dependencies are loaded from `WEB-INF/lib`.

If you are developing in an IDE and running your program in it, you might also have to add the jar to your project build path.

Comment: Thanks for the response - tried that along the way as well. Behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Just to be clear - I tried removing it completely from $CATALINA_HOME/lib and putting it in WEB-INF/lib, not putting it in both places simultaneously.

Comment: Try adding it to the build path too, if you are using eclipse for example.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sotirios Delimanolis mentioned (+1) try to put the jar under `WEB-INF/lib` of your application.

The fact that the class is found using your manual code and cannot be found via Spring signals that the problem is in class loader. When you call `Class.forName()` you are definitely using the system class loader, so the class is loaded from catalina lib directory. I cannot explain why it works when you are calling `getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass()` from you DAO: it in this case the same application class loader should be used. But probably I do not know deeply enough how does Spring itself play with class loaders.

Comment: In this case Spring uses Catalina WebappClassLoader so the problem likely is not with Spring. I would suggest reverting to fresh Tomcat install to see if that resolves the issue. Jars in WEB-INF/lib are definitely picked up by Catalina classloader unless configs have been changed.